# How to fetch particular values from SQlite for given date?

Tags: android, sqlite

Here Following is my Code.I want to fetch data for the date passed in function but I can not able to get them by using following code.So anybody can help me.Thanks In advance.

```
// Getting All Call Details
        public ArrayList<Get_Call_Logs> getAllCallLDetails(String date) {
                    ArrayList<Get_Call_Logs> callDetailsList = new ArrayList<Get_Call_Logs>();
                    // Select All Query
                    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CALL_LOG + " WHERE Datetime('"+ KEY_DATETIME +"') = Datetime('"+ date +"')";
                    System.out.println("selectQuery =======>"+selectQuery);
                    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        // looping through all rows and adding to list
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                // Adding call Log Details to list
                                callDetailsList.add(new Get_Call_Logs(cursor.getInt(0), 
                                        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),
                                        cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(7)), Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(8)),cursor.getString(9)));
                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }
                    }

                    // return contact list
                    return callDetailsList;
                }
```

location_details.addAll(db.getAllLocationHistoryDetails(dat)); This is a line from where I am calling the function and I have implement a date picker.A selected date from date picker is being passed in this.and the formate of selected dated is "dd/MM/yyyy" and date stored in table in "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa" formate. now what I want that I have to dispaly data for selected date from date picker from Sqlite table.

Answer (score 0):

looks fine but can you try this if this will not work then double check your select query..

```
       cursor.moveToFirst();
        //int i = 0;
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            callDetailsList.add(new Get_Call_Logs(cursor.getInt(0), 
                                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),
                                    cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(7)), Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(8)),cursor.getString(9)));

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```

Most important don't forget to close the cursor and db connection

Answer (score 0):

`KEY_DATETIME` is a column name and should not be `'quoted'` as an SQL string literal. Change to:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CALL_LOG + " WHERE Datetime("+ KEY_DATETIME +") = Datetime('"+ date +"')";
```

If there's still a problem, please edit your question and provide some actual data for the datetime column and the format of `date` param.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I am sorry to say that your given solution is Not Working.

Comment: Please provide some additional details so the other problems can be addressed.

Comment: location_details.addAll(db.getAllLocationHistoryDetails(dat)); This is a line from where I am calling the function and I have implement a date picker.A selected date from date picker is being passed in this.and the formate of selected dated is "dd/MM/yyyy" and date stored in table in "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa" formate.
now what I want that I have to dispaly data for selected date from date picker from Sqlite table.